# why does command line execution gives different result to script execution in powershell

Tags: powershell

Running the following command in powershell command prompt works as i would expect:

```
Get-Service "my_service"
*output*
 Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  my_service          My_SERVICE
```

However if make a ps1 scritp as follows my output is not what i would expect.

```
$my_service_check = Get-Service "my_service"
echo "My Service Status: $my_service_check"

*output*
my_service:  System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
```

why does the script not return the same output as the command?

Comment: What output do you expect? Or are you just looking for an explanation why it happens?

Comment: In my script i was expecting to see output like i see when i run the command in the prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more to do with where you have the quotation marks in the echo statement.

In your example, $my_service_check is a [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=netframework-4.8) object- it's not a string that just contains the data you see. You could call methods on it, for example- $my_service_check.Start().

Now if you had

```
echo "My Service Status:" $my_service_check
```

PowerShell is smart enough to realize you want to output the human-readable data in that object- and you get the pretty results.

Because you have

```
echo "My Service Status: $my_service_check"
```

PowerShell is displaying the object itself as a string- which is almost never what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks @Mark, that makes sense. Previously i have created a variable using get-content and select-string. Is that object a string because im explicitly saying get the content of the file and choose the string that matches where as here im not explicitly selecting a string?

Comment: Sort of. Select-String will actually return a Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo object, it just happens that particular type of object works better when you display it. 

I suspect this is because that class was designed by the PowerShell team, while ServiceController comes from .NET Framework, and was designed with a language like C# or VB.NET in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple one:

```
echo "My Service Status:" $my_service_check
```

Comment: previously i have echoed text and my variable inside quotes. can you tell me why it works outside of quotes as you suggest but not inside?

Comment: echo "my service: $myservice" - it say's object.Tostring() , and here echo "my service:" $myservice we print object

Answer (score 1):

Using the below script seems to output the results as you want it:

```
$myService = Get-Service #SERVICE_NAME

Write-Host "My service: " $myService

Pause
```

Output:

> My service: SERVICE_NAME
>
> Press Enter to cotinue...: